# Desktop freezes shortly after login

Tags: grub2, 19.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.04 (not a dual boot, it's on its own dedicated disk) and shortly after login, the desktop freezes and this keeps on happening.

I have a Nvidia graphics card, which according to my research doesn't mix well with Linux. From what I gathered, I would need to boot Ubuntu in safe mode.

However, neither the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key nor the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key bring up GRUB (tried both).
 
Is there a way to force grub to display, or to boot to the terminal where the drivers can be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

AMD Ryzen 2500 here
I have to frequently edit my /boot/grub/grub.cfg file for the timeouts to get Grub menu to appear.

```
sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

ctrl=w    "timeout" enter

and edit these two to a positive number in seconds. they default back to zero with grub update, and did it this week with nothing else done.

if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi

to edit it though you need to boot onto a live CD  and mount your main partition